# How can the below line generate sonar qube issue of always evaluating to false?

Tags: java, null, sonarqube, conditional-statements, sonarqube-5.0

I have the below lines of code and sonarqube is saying,

> "Change this condition so that it doesn't always evaluate to false"

.

Below is the line.

```
if (params.isEmpty() && params == null) {
        throw new ServiceSDKException("Parameters cannot be empty or null!");
    }
```

Below is the whole method in case you need.

```
public void init(String params) throws ServiceSDKException {
        if (params.isEmpty() && params == null) {
            throw new ServiceSDKException("Parameters cannot be empty or null!");
        }
        String[] configParams = params.split(",");
        options.setMqttURL(configParams[0]);
        options.setMqttClientID(configParams[1]);
        try {
            options.setWillMessage("v1/items/mqtt/0/event/will"
                    , "Last will"
                    , 2, true);
            new File("./db").mkdir();
            edgeNode = EdgeNodeFactory.createMQTTChannel("./db", options,
                    subscriptionTask, 500, 500);
            isClientConnected = true;
        } catch (EdgeNodeException e) {
            isClientConnected = false;
            throw new ServiceSDKException("EdgeNodeException occurred", e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: if params is null, you will get a NullPointerException. You should be checking for null first, and then isEmpty() with an or operation ( || )

Comment: Nothing is both `""` and `null`. Thus the condition can never evaluate as true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (params.isEmpty() && params == null)
```

If you've successfully executed `params.isEmpty` without throwing a `NullPointerException`, then `params` is necessarily non-null.

I think perhaps you meant:

```
if (params == null || params.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
if (params.isEmpty() && params == null) {
```

is bringing you to a dead code since they can never be both true.

that is the reason why the **sonarqube** is complaining.

## Why:

String#isEmpty() is a method that returns a boolean if the String is not null referenced

## Quickfix:

Change the logical test for:

```
 if (params.isEmpty() || params == null) {
```